# ggplot 2: Combining free and fixed scales among facet_wrap panels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

When plotting multiple panels using `facet_wrap`, is it possible to allow scales to be free between rows of panels (**but fixed among the columns within each row of panels**)?

In other words, in the following example, would it be possible allow the y scale to be free for each each species, but be fixed across all years for that species?

> e.g. ideally, each "ant" panel across the top row would have a y scale
>   of say 0:400, while each "emu" panel across the bottom row would have
>   a y scale of say 100:500.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
d=as.data.frame(cbind(sample(1:500), c(1:500)))
colnames(d) = c("x","y")
d$year=gl(5,20,labels=c("2001","2002", "2003", "2004","2005"))
d$species=gl(5,25,labels=c("ant","bee","crab","donkey","emu"))
qplot(x, y, data = d)+facet_wrap(~species+year, scales = "free_y", drop = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to use `facet_grid()` instead of `facet_wrap()` to have `species` as rows and `year` as columns. So y axis will be the same for all column in one row.

```
qplot(x, y, data = d)+
  facet_grid(species~year, scales = "free_y", drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Didzis Elferts, this is exactly what I was looking for.